# Delphi:How to run Form2 On Form1.TMoviePlayer

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-xe3, movieplayer

This Form1

```
movieplayer1.UsePitchTempo:=false;
movieplayer1.FileName :=FileNamePlay;
txtDur.Text := Format('%f', [Form111.movieplayer1.Duration] );
txtHeight.Text :=  Format('%d', [Form111.movieplayer1.VideoHeight] );
txtWidth.Text :=  Format('%d', [Form111.movieplayer1.VideoWidth] );
TrackBar1.Min := 0;
TrackBar1.Max :=10000;
TrackBar1.Position :=10000;
movieplayer1.SoundVolume:=0;
movieplayer1.Play();
movieplayer1.AspectRatio :=false;
movieplayer1.Width :=  screen.DesktopWidth  ;
movieplayer1.Height :=  screen.DesktopHeight ;
Form2.Show;
```

This Form2

```
Form2.Color :=0;
Form2.TransparentColor := true;
Form2.TransparentColorValue :=0;
Form2.DoubleBuffered := true
```

...
TextForm2 Flashing  on movieplayer1 Form1 Play .
Fast Involuntarily.
I want.
Text on the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PopupMenu
ShowModal
Check propertismovieplayer1
```